# Passing 2 Parameters to Laravel Routes - Resources

Tags: php, laravel, routes, resources

I'm trying to build my routes using resources so that I can pass two parameters into my resources.

I'll give you a few examples of how the URLS would look:

```
domain.com/dashboard
domain.com/projects
domain.com/project/100
domain.com/project/100/emails
domain.com/project/100/email/3210
domain.com/project/100/files
domain.com/project/100/file/56968
```

So you can see I always need to have reference to the project_id and also the email/file id etc.

I realize I can do this manually by writing all routes by hand, but I'm trying to stick to the resource model.

I figured something like this might work?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'project'], function(){
  Route::group(['prefix' => '{project_id}'], function($project_id){

    // Files
    Route::resource('files', 'FileController');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know about resources

```
Route::resource('files', 'FileController');
```

The above mentioned resource will route the following urls.

Few Actions Handled By Resource Controller for your `Route::resource('files', 'FileController');`

```
Route::get('files',FileController@index) // get req will be routed to the index() function in your controller
Route::get('files/{val}',FileController@show) // get req with val will be routed to the show() function in your controller
Route::post('files',FileController@store) // post req will be routed to the store() function in your controller
Route::put('files/{id}',FileController@update) // put req with id will be routed to the update() function in your controller
Route::delete('files',FileController@destroy) // delete req will be routed to the destroy() function in your controller
```

the single `resource` Mentioned above will do all the listed `routing`

Apart from those you have to write your `custom route`

In your scenario of

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'project'], function(){
  Route::group(['prefix' => '{project_id}'], function($project_id){

    // Files
    Route::resource('files', 'FileController');

  });
});
```

`domain.com/project/100/files` 
 if its a `get` request will be routed to `FileController@index`
 if its a `post` request will be routed to `FileController@store`

**if your "`domain.com/project/100/file/56968`" is changed to "`domain.com/project/100/files/56968`"**  (file to files)then the following rooting will occur...

`domain.com/project/100/files/56968`
 if its a `get` request will be routed to `FileController@show`
 if its a `put` request will be routed to `FileController@update`
 if its a `delete` request will be routed to `FileController@destroy`

and it has no impact on any other `url`s you have mentioned

Provided, you need to have [RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: That explains it well, I didn't realise this would pass the project id through to method as well, but it does indeed appear to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For the request like '/project/100/file/56968', you must specify your route like this:

```
Route::resource('project.file', 'FileController');
```

And then you can get parameters at the show method of the controller:

```
public function show($project, $file) {
    dd([
        '$project' => $project,
        '$file' => $file
    ]);
}
```

The result of this example will be:

```
array:2 [▼
  "$project" => "100"
  "$file" => "56968"
]
```