# .htaccess to redirect to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im trying to do the following: if I go to www.example.com/panel -> i want to open index.php in folder panel, if I go to www.example.com/panel/somehing - i want it to translate this to www.example.com/panel/index.php?content=something

Now I've tried all sort of possible solutions here that includes redirecting to sub-folder like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/public/$1 [L]
```

but this completely overrides my main index.php and redirects everything to sub-folder.

And I do use simple conditions and rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteRule ^check-out/?$ index.php?content=check-out [NC,L]
```

And this works nicely, the way I want to.

So if I'm in location

```
www.example.com/panel/user
```

I need something like

```
RewriteRule ^panel/([^/]+)$ panel/index.php?content=$1 [NC,L]
```

Where **([^/]+)$** and **$1** would in this case represent "user" and site should redirect to

```
www.example.com/panel/index.php?content=user
```

Comment: You can look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662758/rewrite-url-with-2-or-more-params/47663846#47663846

Comment: Bit unclear, what is name of subfolder, Is it just `panel/` or `subfolder/public/`?

Comment: subfolder is panel with its own index.php in it

Comment: @Zyigh thank you for provided answer but that's just way over my php knowledge and I'm far to short on time to study your provided solution.

Comment: checkout works like thi www.example.com/check-out -> translated to www.example.com/index.php?conent=check-out and then in my index.php file i catch $_GET['content']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `panel/.htaccess` have this code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php?content=$0 [L,QSA]
```